# How would I sync up a "random.choice" with a different line?

Tags: python

What could I put in the `len()` so that whatever is chosen in the `new_song_list` is also put into there?

(song is a value I made earlier in the code, this is only a snippet).

```
print(song, "\n", random.choice(new_song_list))
print(len(), "letters long")
```

Comment: Instead of passing the chosen value _directly_ to `print`, store it in a variable first. Then you can later pass the variable to `print()`, *and* pass it as an argument to `len()`.

Comment: new_song = random.choice(new_song_list) print(len(new_song))

Comment: @Charles Duffy I have tried this and get ```TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len()``` as a respones.

Comment: @Rayner, that error message is correct; methods don't have a `len()`. We'd need to see what you were doing when you got that error to know why you had a method, instead of a string, in your variable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, I have worked out the problem, and a lot needs tweaked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a randomly-chosen value in more than one place, store it in a variable.

```
import random

new_song_list = [ "A", "BB", "CCC" ] # sample data
new_song = random.choice(new_song_list)
print(new_song)
print(len(new_song), "letters long")
```